# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? I am running ubuntu sub operating system, is it something to do with that? Here's my code:

```
section .data
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

And here is how I assemble it:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o exit.o exit.s

ld exit.o -o exit
```

It shows:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: AFAIK linux uses syscall instead of int80 on 64 bit. Either way, it'd be easier and (somewhat more) portable if you'd call `exit` instead.

Comment: While that is 32 bit code, it should work. Maybe your ubuntu is without 32 bit compatibility support (unlikely).

Comment: *sub operating system,* sounds like you're describing Windows with WSL.  It's like Linux without CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION so it doesn't support the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI.